# My husband became a custodian on our son's 529 plan when my mother-in-law passed . Does the 15 year clock start all over again on IRA Conversion?

Tags: united-states, ira, 529-plan, education-savings

My mother-in-law opened an account for our son when he was very young. She died 10 years ago, and the change in custodian resulted in a new account registration. So, although the account looks like it is only 10 years old, I believe it is much older (since he was the youngest grandchild and she was diligent on these matters).

He is not attending college, and we would like to convert this account into an IRA over time. I'm hoping the investment company will be willing to provide evidence of the original account open date, but that doesn't mean the IRS will like what they see. Any insight on IRS opinions would be welcomed.